# jQuery val returns empty string

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following html code in my application:

```
<tr style="cursor:pointer;">
    <td>100101</td>
    <td>Monkey</td>
    <td>Nuts<td>
    <td>Cow</td>
    <td>Soup</td>
    <td>Chicken</td>
    <td>Leg</td>
    <td class="non-clicky">
        <p>Click</p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

What I need to do is get the value of the first td when I click on the class non-clicky.
So I have the code:

```
alert($('.non-clicky:first').parent().children('td:first').val());
```

This code results in the value of "" -- empty string being returned and not the result 100101.

So, instead i tried the code:

```
alert($('.non-clicky:first').siblings(':first').val());
```

Again this resulted in the value being empty string, why is it `.val()` is returning an empty string instead of the correct result?

I tried the code below and this gives me the correct answer, but I am curious as to why val does not. What is the difference between val and text?

```
alert($('.non-clicky:first').siblings(':first').text());
// and 
alert($('.non-clicky:first').parent().children('td:first').text());
```

Note:

The code above makes use of `$('.non-clicky:first')` this was only for my testing purposes in the code it will be within a jquery click event.

Comment: It seems you have not read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Comment: ""The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as input"" is primarily used which implies it can be used for other things also.

Comment: And what makes you think that "the other" use is getting the text content of elements? But I see your point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/), [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is for getting the value of an input element.

Comment: thanks @kevin-b, edited your answer a little but it hit the mark.

Comment: @aspect I've always wondered if there was possibly a better way to handle `.val()` vs `.text()`, but they've both been around for so long that changing either of them would cause major backwards compatibility issues and making `.val()` mimic `.text()` on non-inputs would just bloat the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `text()`:

```
$('.non-clicky').click(function(){ alert($(this).siblings().first().text()); });
```

Comment: Was asking why i need to use text instead of val in the question. Not a solution to the problem.